# SQL Union with "Ranks"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am writing a query to search a table for a specific user, this will provide an exact match and potential matches.

Essentially, the users email address is unique, therefore I do not need to return more than this row, however beyond this I need to return all the potential users with a 'rank' of how likely a match they are.

I want the query to be as efficient as possible, and to this point have avoided a cursor as I felt it not to be neccessary. Here is an example of my current query.

```
    SELECT 
            tt.userId,
            tt.UserName,
            ad.*,
            1 AS 'Rank'
        FROM
            Users.User tt
        LEFT JOIN
            General.[Address] ad ON tt.AddressId = ad.AddressId
        WHERE
            tt.EmailAddress = @EmailAddress
    UNION

        SELECT 
            tt.userId,
            tt.UserName,
            ad.*,
            2 AS 'Rank'
        FROM
            Users.User tt
        LEFT JOIN
            General.[Address] ad ON tt.AddressId = ad.AddressId
        WHERE
            tt.LastName = @LastName
            AND tt.BirthDate = @DOB
```

Obviously the primary flaw here is, if the email address matched, the same user is going to be appearing in the second query also and so on. Also as I need to rank these searches the union isn't going to match the rows as a duplicate so I will get the same user back several times.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that **if** a user for an email address is found, then no matching should occur on Lastname and Birthdate?

Comment: Correct. This is exactly what I am after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `union` at all:

```
SELECT tt.userId, tt.UserName, ad.*,
       (CASE WHEN tt.EmailAddress = @EmailAddress THEN 1
             WHEN tt.LastName = @LastName AND tt.BirthDate = @DOB THEN 2
        END) as [Rank]
FROM Users.User tt LEFT JOIN
     General.[Address] ad
     ON tt.AddressId = ad.AddressId
WHERE (tt.EmailAddress = @EmailAddress) OR
      (tt.LastName = @LastName AND tt.BirthDate = @DOB);
```

Obviously, it is easy to add additional conditions, such as a new ranking when all three columns match.

Comment: Thanks for this - Brain was just melting on a Friday! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, as no sample data, however, I believe this will work. If not, please post some DDL and Consumable Sample Data:

```
WITH Results AS(
    SELECT tt.UserID,
           tt.UserName,
           ad.*,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CASE WHEN tt.EmailAddress = @EmailAddress THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS RN
    FROM Users.[User] tt
         LEFT JOIN General.[Address] ad ON tt.AddressId = ad.AddressID
    WHERE tt.EmailAddress = @EmailAddress
       OR (tt.LastName = @LastName
      AND  tt.BirthDate = @DOB))
SELECT *
FROM Results
WHERE RN = 1;
```

The `DENSE_RANK()` means that you end up with 2 groups, however, if no email address is found, all the results will end up with a RN of 1. Otherwise, those with the same email address will have an RN of 1, while the rest 2 (meaning that those matches won't be displayed with to the `WHERE` clause outside the CTE.